# Form_for form in ruby doesn't work when the page loads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for, turbolinks

I have a form in a ruby app that doesn't work when the page loads; when I click on "refresh," then it works just fine:

```
         <div class="newtodoline">  
          <div class="description text_field">
            <%= form_for @todo do |form| %>
              <%= form.text_field :description, placeholder: 'Add new todo', size: 25 %></div>
          <div class="days_old">
              <%= form.hidden_field :list_id, :value => @list.id %></div>
          <div class="completed savetodo">
              <%= form.submit 'Save Todo' %></div>
            <% end %>
```

I imagine the problem lies with turbolinks, but as I'm using turbolinks events to spark a javascript page transition, I'd rather not turn it off . . . can anyone suggest a way I can get this form to work the first time the page loads?

I may also have a problem in my controllers, though again when I refresh the page the form works, so I don't think that's the issue . . . anyhow, this form creates a new todo, which requires the create action from the todos controller; but the form itself is on the list show view. So, in my lists controller I have:

```
  def show
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
    @cutoff = @list.cutoff
    if @list.todos.exists? then  
      @list.todos.each do |t|
        if t.age_of_todo > @cutoff then
          t.delete
        end
      end
    end
    @todos = @list.todos
    @todo = Todo.new
  end
```

and in my todos controller:

```
  def create
    @todo = Todo.new(todo_params)
    if @todo.valid?
      @todo.save
      redirect_to list_path(id:@todo.list_id), notice: 'Your new TODO was saved!'
    else
      flash[:notice] = 'You forgot to enter a description. Please try again.'
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end

  private

  def todo_params
    params.require(:todo).permit(:description, :list_id)
  end
```

Do I have to shut down turbolinks and find a new way to call my page transitions, or is there another way to make this form work?

Thanks!

EDIT: I should mention that I've tried shutting off turbolinks, and it does fix the problem; unfortunately, then my pretty page transitions also shut down, and I'm not sure how to attach those transitions to html page change events. I'd love to know how turbolinks is failing this particular form, and how to fix it while still using turbolinks! Does anyone know where the code for the form_for helper itself is?

Comment: define doesn't work?  do you get an error? does it not submit? does it not render?  How do you get to the page, are you using lots of  binds in jquery. If so have you looked at(https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks)

Comment: No error, just nothing happens. No binds, no jquery, just a FadeIn effect on a turbolink event (page:change).

Comment: how about browser console? it should at least give you something there, if not check network on the console

Comment: the browser console doesn't seem to notice when I click on "submit."

Comment: try to disable turbo links first to make sure it is the culprit. You can try to use jquery-turbolinks gem. It solves a lot of page loading problems associated with turbo links and javascript.

Comment: The error is almost certainly in the Javascript. Can you paste that as well? How does it get initialized?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any issue other than the order of `HTML` tags opened and closed, yes I found you missed to close a `div` tag. Use the code below:

```
<div class="newtodoline">
  <%= form_for @todo do |form| %>
    <div class="description text_field">
      <%= form.text_field :description, placeholder: 'Add new todo', size: 25 %>
    </div>
    <div class="days_old">
      <%= form.hidden_field :list_id, :value => @list.id %>
    </div>
    <div class="completed savetodo">
      <%= form.submit 'Save Todo' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I'm not pretty sure about the issue, but it might help you :)

Comment: Thanks so much! This didn't fix the problem, but always a good idea to close divs . . .